# Single country coastlines in Python Matplotlib Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

In the image below I am using cartopy to plot coastlines. But, I only wish to have the coastlines of Australia, and not the surrounding countries. Is there a way to remove the other countries.

Here is some sample code with the key steps in it for this problem:

```
fig  = plt.figure(figsize = (16, 16))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4,2, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)

for i in range(1,9):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i - 1], projection = ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.coastlines(resolution = '50m')
    ax.set_extent([110, 155, -23,-8.5])
```

[image].

Comment: Bump!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!